# Google Chrome Context Menu: How use it? How or were view javascript console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console, google-chrome-extension, contextmenu

I'm trying to learn Chrome extensions. My problem is that I can't able use context menus. Nothing appears in the context menu. And how do I see the JavaScript console? I see nothing even there.

JavaScript code:

```
var arr_context = ["all", "page", "frame", "selection", "link", "editable", "image", "video", "audio"];
for(i=0; i<arr_context.length; i++){
    var title = arr_context[i];
    var menu1 = chrome.contextMenus.create({"type":"normal", "title":"Menu " + title, "contexts":arr_context, "onclick":callBack });
}

function callBack(info, tab){ console.log(info.menuItemId + "; URL: " + tab.url); }
/////////// NOTHING CONSOLE LOG ISSUE ///////////////////
```

Manifest:

```
{
    "name": "First Extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "The first extensione tha I made",
    "permission":["contextMenus"],
    "background_page": "background_page.html",
    "browser_action":{
                        "name": "My First Extension!",
                        "default_icon": "Chrome_icon32bn.png",
                        /* "default_popup": "popup.html", */
                        "default_title": "My First Extension!"
    },
    "icons": {
                "16": "Chrome_icon19color.png",
                "48": "Chrome_icon32color.png",
                "128": "Chrome_icon.png"
    }
}
```

---

Partly resolved: It was an error in file *manifest.json*. I wrote "permission" rather than "permissions".

But the second question remains. Why don't I see any *console.log* issue?

Comment: Try using code formatting text time ;) have you tried a example extension with chrome.contextMenus API ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In reply to why your `console.log` doesn't show, I had a similar problem *(and I only just started Chrome Extension development today, so that's no surprise!)*, for me it was solved by going to the **Extensions page**, and clicking on the link **"_generated_background_page.html"** listed under my extension.

As I hadn't made my own background HTML page, one is generated by Chrome automatically. 
You must inspect this page for your console logs to be seen.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> and select the "Console" tab on the pop-up panel.

On Mac, press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> or <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> and select the "Console" tab on the pop-up panel.

Comment: No, I know where is javascript console, but with Chrome Extension Examples not working, i can't able to read console issue.
And how I can't able to generate a context menu?

Answer (score 0):

In response to the Console question, you need to right click on your browser action and choose, "inspect popup" to see the console output for a browser action.

Comment: Yesssssssss i know...but in this case don't able to see any log issue :(
I don't know why, it's strange!

Comment: Can you post the code in context where you are logging to the console?

Comment: I opened "background page", and console report wrote that: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setBadgeText' of undefined

Maybe is that the problem cause other logs not work?
But aniway I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Almost all the Chrome Extensions API's fail silently.
I think you need to read the documentation a little more:

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/contextMenus/#method-create

I think you need to at least also provide

- `type`
- `contexts`
- `onclick`
- and last but not least `callback ( optional function )`

It is called when the item has been created in the browser. If there were any problems creating the item, details will be available in `chrome.extension.lastError`.

Comment: The link is broken: *"Aw, Snap! We couldn't find that page."*

Comment: Fixed the link, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me using your manifest stripped down to just a popup page containing just this script:

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    "type":"normal", 
    "title":"Menu ", 
    "contexts":["all", "page", "frame", "selection", "link", "editable", "image","video", "audio"], 
    "onclick": function (info, tab) { 
        console.log(info);
        console.log(tab);
    } 
});
```

I see both objects in the console (dev tools window for inspecting the popup) after clicking the "Menu" context link.

Comment: JUST THE CONSOLE to me it does not work.
If I open the "background page" and open log window see an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'create' of undefined 
o.O'

Comment: "alert" work, but not "console.log" ... and don't understand where is the error.

Comment: So the issue is not with how you are creating contextMenus, but elsewhere in your code.  I can't really help further without seeing the context around where you are.  I suggest you break the code into smaller pieces and liberally log everything you can out, leading up to the line where the error is.  That should give you more clues as to where the problem lies.